# Checkbox value not keeping UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that creates an html form containing a group of checkboxes that have Chinese characters in their name attribute.  When I submit the form I retrieve these by calling:

`String[] values = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");`

However when I try to look at the individual values the text seems to be coming out with the wrong encoding. In both my servlets I've set the contentType charset to UTF-8 and character encoding to UTF-8. So I'm not sure why it seems to be losing it's encoding.

Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Some other html stuff then.

```
<form action="addVocab" method="get">

<% 
HashMap<String, servlets.Hanzi> hanziMap = Tester.getHanziMap();
HashSet<String> concordance = Tester.getConcordance();
HashSet<String> knownWords = Tester.getKnownWords();
Hanzi hanzi = new Hanzi();
String simp;
LinkedList<String> defList;
for(String s : concordance){
    if( !knownWords.contains(s) ){
        hanzi = hanziMap.get(s);
        simp = hanzi.getSimplified();           
        out.println("<input class=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" name = \"checkbox\" value="+simp+">");
    }
}
```

%>

```
<input class = "submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

When I view the page everything comes out looking fine.  I can see the characters just fine.  However when I make a submission the characters come out like they are in a different encoding.  In the servlet I am checking it in this way.

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("In the server");
    String[] values = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");

    out.println(values.length);
    for(String s : values){
        out.println( s );
    }
```

When it prints out it prints out like this.  å¤§ å­¤ç¬ èªå·± åå®¶ æ¶å  I don't understand why because as far as I can tell everything is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Right now to observe the problem, we would have to create a checkbox, pick some values, and test.  Odds are excellent that we would do it in an entirely different manner than you did, with different values.  That means we won't be solving your problem (if we even encounter one).  To make this place work for you, you need to write a small self contained example of the issue.  One that can be compiled, and demonstrates the issue.  Then you will have dozens of people who are willing to do the last bit (fix the problem) fighting to fix it first.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I followed your advice and added code.